# Memory game with images javafx wrong Image opens

Tags: java, javafx

I've been working on a memory card game on javaFX where you click a card and it flips and you click another and it flips if they are the same it stays if the are different they close, I followed this tutorial but I want to to change it from letters to images, the problem is  when ever I click a tile an image on a different tile is shown

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


import java.util.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    private int num_of_pairs = 8;
    private int num_per_row = 4;


     Tile selected = null;
    private int clickCount=2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
//        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");



        Pane root = new Pane();

        ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>();
        ImageView[] puzz=new ImageView[num_of_pairs];

        for(int i=0;i< puzz.length;i++){
            puzz[i]= new ImageView("image.jpeg");
            puzz[i].setFitHeight(110);
            puzz[i].setFitWidth(110);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_pairs; i++) {

            tiles.add(new Tile(puzz[i]));
            tiles.add(new Tile(puzz[i]));



        }

        Collections.shuffle(tiles);

        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {

            Tile tile = tiles.get(i);

            tile.setTranslateX(120 * (i % num_per_row));
            tile.setTranslateY(120 * (i / num_per_row));

            System.out.println(120*(i%num_per_row));
            System.out.println(120*(i/num_per_row));


            root.getChildren().add(tile);


        }




        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 550));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }




    class Tile extends StackPane {




        ImageView image;




        Tile(ImageView image) {
            this.image=image;


            Rectangle border = new Rectangle(120, 120);

            border.setFill(null);

            border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);



            getChildren().addAll(this.image,border);

            setOnMouseClicked(this::handleMouseClick);


            close();
        }

        public void handleMouseClick(MouseEvent event){

                if (isOpen() || clickCount==0)
                    return;
                clickCount--;
                if (selected == null) {
                    selected = this;
                    open(() ->{});
                }else{
                    open(() -> {
                        if(!hasSameValue(selected)){
                            selected.close();
                            this.close();
                        }
                        selected=null;
                        clickCount=2;
                    });
                }

            }


        public boolean isOpen() {
            return image.getOpacity() == 1;
        }

        public void close() {
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), image);
            ft.setToValue(0);
            ft.play();
        }

        public void open(Runnable action) {
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), image);
            ft.setToValue(1);
            ft.setOnFinished(e -> action.run());
            ft.play();
        }

        public boolean hasSameValue(Tile other) {
            return image.getImage().equals(other.image.getImage());
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes (such as `ImageView`s) can only appear once in any scene graph. You are attempting to use each `ImageView` twice in your root pane; essentially what happens here is the second time you add the `ImageView` to the root (via the `Tile`), it's removed from the first tile and placed in the second. Then if you click on the `Tile` corresponding to the *first* time the image was added, the image appears using the coordinates from the *second* time it was added.

Instead, you can create an array of `Image`s, and use each `Image` twice in two *different* `ImageView`s. Something like this should work:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


import java.util.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    private int num_of_pairs = 8;
    private int num_per_row = 4;


    Tile selected = null;
    private int clickCount=2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");



        Pane root = new Pane();

        ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>();

        // Note array changed to Image:
        Image[] puzz=new Image[num_of_pairs];

        for(int i=0;i< puzz.length;i++){
            puzz[i]= new Image("image.jpeg");
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_pairs; i++) {

            // Create two *different* ImageViews for each Image:

            ImageView first = new ImageView(puzz[i]);
            first.setFitHeight(110);
            first.setFitWidth(110);

            ImageView second = new ImageView(puzz[i]);
            second.setFitHeight(110);
            second.setFitWidth(110);

            tiles.add(new Tile(first));
            tiles.add(new Tile(second));



        }

        Collections.shuffle(tiles);

        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {

            Tile tile = tiles.get(i);

            tile.setTranslateX(120 * (i % num_per_row));
            tile.setTranslateY(120 * (i / num_per_row));

            System.out.println(120*(i%num_per_row));
            System.out.println(120*(i/num_per_row));


            root.getChildren().add(tile);


        }




        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 550));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }




    class Tile extends StackPane {




        ImageView image;




        Tile(ImageView image) {
            this.image=image;


            Rectangle border = new Rectangle(120, 120);

            border.setFill(null);

            border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);



            getChildren().addAll(this.image,border);

            setOnMouseClicked(this::handleMouseClick);


            close();
        }

        public void handleMouseClick(MouseEvent event){

                if (isOpen() || clickCount==0)
                    return;
                clickCount--;
                if (selected == null) {
                    selected = this;
                    open(() ->{});
                }else{
                    open(() -> {
                        if(!hasSameValue(selected)){
                            selected.close();
                            this.close();
                        }
                        selected=null;
                        clickCount=2;
                    });
                }

            }


        public boolean isOpen() {
            return image.getOpacity() == 1;
        }

        public void close() {
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), image);
            ft.setToValue(0);
            ft.play();
        }

        public void open(Runnable action) {
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), image);
            ft.setToValue(1);
            ft.setOnFinished(e -> action.run());
            ft.play();
        }

        public boolean hasSameValue(Tile other) {
            return image.getImage().equals(other.image.getImage());
        }


    }
}
```